# Getting Error while using MySql.net connector in Ado.net

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

this is my web.config file. I am using MySql Dot net Connector in MVC3 which has a support with ADO.NET Entity Framework 
When i create a model through Ado.net I get connected and everything is established successfully. But when I run the project after logging in i get this error

```
" Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.
```

"

Some of the code of web.config

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
<clear />
<remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
<add name="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data,Version=6.7.4.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
<connectionStrings>   
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="metadata=res://*/KPTSANCTIONS.csdl|res://*/KPTSANCTIONS.ssdl|res://*/KPTSANCTIONS.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=localhost;user id=root;password=insane1234;database=kpt_sanctions&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

here is the stack trace

```
   [ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.]
System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName) +1426271
System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateEntityConnection(ConnectionStringSettings setting, String csdl, String ssdl, String msl) +116
System.Web.Providers.ModelHelper.CreateMembershipEntities(ConnectionStringSettings setting) +82
System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.GetPasswordWithFormat(String userName, Boolean updateLastLoginActivityDate, Int32& status, String& password, Int32& format, String& salt, Int32& failedPasswordAttemptCount, Int32& failedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, Boolean& isApproved, DateTime& lastLoginDate, DateTime& lastActivityDate) +221
System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String userName, String password, Boolean updateLastActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved, String& salt, Int32& passwordFormat) +158
System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.CheckPassword(String userName, String password, Boolean updateLastActivityDate, Boolean failIfNotApproved) +69
System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +297
System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(String username, String password) +26
MISSanctions.Controllers.LoginController.ValidateUser(LoginModel model, String returnUrl) in e:\dotnet projects\webs\MISSanctions\MISSanctions\Controllers\LoginController.cs:26
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +245
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +214
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +55
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +253
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass17.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__14() +21
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +191
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +324
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +106
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +91
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +10
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +34
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +19
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +48
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f) +7
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action) +22
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +60
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9628972
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: What does the stack trace say?

Comment: I updated the stack trace